# Probability of rounding off a fraction to an even number

Tags: probability

In a quiz the following question was asked :

""Let x and y be two random numbers between 0 and 1. What is the probability that $\frac{x}{y}$ rounds to an even number?""

My friend calculated the answer to be $$\frac{5}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

which is roughly equal to 46 percent. I don't know whether his answer is definitely correct but could not find any flaws in his reasoning or calculation. So my question arises as follows:

Since x/y has values ranging from $0$ to infinity, why isn't the probability of rounding x/y to an even or odd number equal.

$\mathbf{EDIT:}$My friend used probability spaces in his answer. He plotted the two numbers x and y on a graph with both x and y varying from $0$ to $1$. This gives us a unit square. Then he calculated the area of the regions of the square which sastisfied the condition that x/y rounds to an even number. This gave him an infinite number of triangles with decreasing area. He applied summation on the areas of the triangles to get the answer.

Comment: Can you describe your friend's idea?

Answer (score 5):

The probability that $\frac{x}{y}$ rounds to $0$, i.e that $ 2x \lt y$, is $\frac14$.

The probability that $\frac{x}{y}$ rounds to $2$ , i.e that $3y \le 2x \lt 5y$, is $\frac13-\frac15$, and similarly rounding to $4$ is $\frac17-\frac19$, to $6$ is $\frac1{11}-\frac1{13}$, and so on.

Since $1 - \frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19-\frac1{11}+\frac1{13}- \cdots = \frac\pi{4}$, the probability of rounding to an even number is $\frac{1}{4}+1-\frac\pi{4}$ which is the result your friend had.

Your friend's diagram probably looked something like this

[image: rounding to even]

with the black areas corresponding to "rounding to even". There is no reason to expect the black and white areas to be the same: rounding to $1$ with a probability of $\frac{5}{12}$ is more likely than any other result.

As an empirical check using R:

```
set.seed(1)
cases <- 1000000
x <- runif(cases)
y <- runif(cases)
z <- round(x/y, 0)
mean( z/2 == floor(z/2) ) # even
```

gives

```
0.464628
```

compared with $\frac{5}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4} \approx 0.4646018$.